# Error al cargar un archivo con Drive Picker en App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

Cada vez que intento cargar un archivo desde el dispositivo del usuario con Drive Picker me devuelve el error 'Server rejected'. Lo he intentado con distintas aplicaciones (incluso la de ejemplo), cambiando el tipo de selección 'MULTI' y 'SIMPLE', el tamaño... pero no funciona. Solo me deja cargar archivos de Google Drive.

[image: Server rejected error]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente me ha resuelto el problema Axel del soporte de Gsuite. Espor un tema de permisos. Copio la respuesta por si pudiera ser de ayuda para otros usuarios:
Por defecto, el Drive Picker tiene acceso de "solo lectura" a la unidad de Drive de un usuario, a menos que su aplicación de App Maker solicite específicamente el acceso de "lectura / escritura". Básicamente, para usar la funcionalidad de carga de archivos, necesita forzar su aplicación App Maker a solicitar acceso de "lectura / escritura". La forma más sencilla de hacerlo es crear una nueva ‘server side script’ y agregar una función simple que requiera acceso de escritura. Por ejemplo:

```
function writeAccess() {  

 DriveApp.addFile();  

}
```

Esta función nunca se ejecutará ni se llamará, pero App Maker reconocerá que necesita acceso de escritura para implementarla y solicitarla al usuario. Así que simplemente agregue un nuevo server script y copie y pegue lo anterior. Al utilizar “Preview” App Maker le solicitara permiso para acceder a su cuenta de Drive. Una vez que el acceso de escritura esté disponible para su aplicación, podrá cargar archivos con Drive Picker.